# Yii multi page form wizard best practice

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I am trying to build a multi-page form with Yii, but am quite new to PHP and Yii and am wondering what the best practice is for writing a multi page form.  So far, what I am planning to do is to add a hidden field named 'step' which contains the current step the user is on in the form (the form is broken into 3 steps/pages).  So with that in mind, this is how I plan to handle the user clicking on previous/next buttons in the Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
 {
  $userModel = new User;

  $data['activityModel'] = $activityModel; 
  $data['userModel'] = $userModel; 

  if (!empty($_POST['step']))
  {
   switch $_POST['step']:
    case '1':
     $this->render('create_step1', $data);
     break;

    case '2':
     $this->render('create_step2', $data);
     break;

  }else
  {
   $this->render('create_step1', $data);
  }
 }
```

Does this approach make sense?  Or am I way off base and there is a much better and more optimized way of doing this in Yii/PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `CHtml::statefulForm` and a [thread at Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/8413-wizard-forms/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. I see you posted in the Yii forum so I assume you've searched around there too but in case you haven't:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/6203-stateful-forms-and-wizards-howto/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/8413-wizard-forms/

What I have done is (just for a simple 2-step ActiveRecord form) taken a single action and divided it up into conditional blocks based on the button name, which Yii POSTs on a form submit (note: doesn't work with ajax submits). Then, depending on which button was hit I render the correct form and set the correct scenario on my model for validation purposes.

A hidden "step" field like you have could serve the same purpose as the checking the submitButton name. I would perhaps save the "step" into the form state instead of adding a hidden field though, but either would be fine.

Some people use the stateful activeForm attribute to save the data from a single step in the wizard, or you can use the session, or even save to a temp database table. In my completely untested example below I am using a the stateful form functionality.

Here is an example of what I basically did for an ActiveRecord form. This goes in the "actionCreate":

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
  $this->redirect(array('home'));
} elseif (isset($_POST['step2'])) {
  $this->setPageState('step1',$_POST['Model']); // save step1 into form state
  $model=new Model('step1');
  $model->attributes = $_POST['Model'];
  if($model->validate())
    $this->render('form2',array('model'=>$model));
  else {
    $this->render('form1',array('model'=>$model));
  }
} elseif (isset($_POST['finish'])) {
  $model=new Model('finish');
  $model->attributes = $this->getPageState('step1',array()); //get the info from step 1
  $model->attributes = $_POST['Model']; // then the info from step2
  if ($model->save())
    $this->redirect(array('home'));
  else {
    $this->render('form2',array('model'=>$model));
} else { // this is the default, first time (step1)
  $model=new Model('new');
  $this->render('form1',array('model'=>$model));
} ?>
```

The forms would look something like this:

Form1:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'id'=>'model-form',
    'stateful'=>true,
));
<!-- form1 fields go here -->
echo CHtml::submitButton("Cancel",array('name'=>'cancel');
echo CHtml::submitButton("On to Step 2 >",array('name'=>'step2');
$this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Form 2:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'id'=>'model-form',
    'stateful'=>true,
));
<!-- form2 fields go here -->
echo CHtml::submitButton("Back to Step 1",array('name'=>'step1');
echo CHtml::submitButton("Finish",array('name'=>'finish');
$this->endWidget(); ?>
```

I hope that is helpful!

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful!  I quite like your approach of using the submit buttons to determine which step to display.  I will also look into the ActiveForm approach, which sounds interesting.

Comment: Thanks allot. Where can i learn more stuff like that? Like professional developing with yii framework.

Comment: regarding "note: doesn't work with ajax submits", this is true, especially in jquery, but you can just append the button name/value to the result of form.serialize and will work

Comment: I've tried that by submit button name, but it never reads step2 button. When I click on step1 button it takes me to step2, when I click on step2 it skips and returns to step1.

Comment: An important piece of information to make your post more complete, in that the model class must manage scenarios for validation of the form fields.

Comment: wow i was searching on net for this from long time, i am sure the above answer is the best solution to divide a single form into multiple, but my problem is, i am a newbie php programmer, currently working on a project using yii2.0 framework, but i have not worked on yii 1.0 framework before , so may be my question is silly but it is complicated for me :) , my question is .. is the above syntax works with yii2.0 framework ??or is the syntax changed in yii2.0 framework for multi step form ??? please help

Comment: @Sadia Naseeba: it will surely **not** work with Yii 2, and even the logic may change a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Yii provides a feature called page states to implement things like a multi step / multi page form wizard.

Lets have a look at the Yii docs first:

> A page state is a variable that is persistent across POST requests of the same page. In order to use persistent page states, the form(s) must be stateful which are generated using {@link CHtml::statefulForm}.

So the forms of every step / page need to be stateful forms. To render a stateful form you just need to set the `CActiveForm::stateful` property to `true` when you start the ActiveForm-widget.
Within your controller you can get and set your page states with `CController::getPageState()` or `CController::setPageState()`.

So these are the basics that work quite well if the implementation of your multi page form wizard is made in the traditional style without AJAX requests.

**If however you want to use AJAX calls to submit step data and display the next step, Yii's page states are not usable.**

Why? All the page states are transported through HTTP-POST within a hidden input field. The input field gets filled by Yii while the so called output processing. The output processing starts **after** the rendering and will replace parts of the output. So **Yii's page states feature  requires the output processing**. AJAX responses on the other hand may become corrupted by it because the output processing may also add `<link>` or `<script>` tags at the beginning of the output to load required JS and CSS files.

In the end I implemented my own version of stateful forms. I am able to get my stateful data with the static function call `ActiveFormWidget::getRequestMultiStepData()` every time I need it.

Notice: There is one disadvantage in my implementation: all stateful data needs to be collected before the form widget will be initialized. But I never had a problem with it until now. However here is the code:

```
class ActiveFormWidget extends CActiveForm
{
    public static $inputNameMultiStepData = '_multiStepData';

    public $multiStep = false;
    public $multiStepData = array();

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        # Hidden-Fields
        if ($this->multiStep) {
            echo Html::hiddenField(static::$inputNameMultiStepData, static::encodeInputData($this->multiStepData));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets all multi step data sent.
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public static function getRequestMultiStepData()
    {
        return isset($_REQUEST[static::$inputNameMultiStepData]) ? static::decodeInputData($_REQUEST[static::$inputNameMultiStepData]) : array();
    }


    /**
     * Encodes form data like Yii does for stateful forms.
     * @param $data
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encodeInputData($data)
    {
        $data = Yii::app()->getSecurityManager()->hashData(serialize($data));

        return base64_encode($data);
    }

    /**
     * Decodes form data like Yii does for stateful forms.
     * @param $data
     * @return bool|mixed
     */
    public static function decodeInputData($data)
    {
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $data = Yii::app()->getSecurityManager()->validateData($data);
        if ($data !== false) {
            return unserialize($data);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```