# Yii 2 - Partial views and form validation scenarios

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need some advice:

We have to create this multi-step form. We either create 1 form *per step*, or, we can **create 1 single form for all steps**.

If we go with the *later*:

If we decide to split a view into multiple **partials views**, how will **activeform** *validation* on those partials be handled?

Should we setup a *validation scenario* per step?

Can I please have your help towards this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548528/yii-multi-page-form-wizard-best-practice